# Send error params to error handler function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have a service that returns this

```
return Upload.http({
    url: requestInfo.data.url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    data: file
});
```

However, I want to catch the error that I'm receiving from the server, and parse it before being returned by the service, because the error, by itself, means nothing to the controllers that call this service.

I tried this:

```
return Upload.http({
    url: requestInfo.data.url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    data: file
}).catch(function(error){
    return $q.reject({fileID: requestInfo.data.file.id});
});
```

**Controller:**

```
 file.upload = itemOperationService.uploadItem(uploadInfo, file);
 file.upload.then(
    handleUploadSuccess, 
    handleUploadError, 
    handleUploadProgress);
```

It works. Now the error handler function receives this object. However, with this approach, I'm not able to call `file.upload.abort()` function anymore, given that it does not exist in the file.upload object . How could I achieve what I want to? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this it may help you.

```
file.upload = itemOperationService.uploadItem(uploadInfo, file);
file.upload.then(
    function(response) {
        //handle success respnse here.
        console.log('get',response)
    },
    function(data) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem with selecting what you want to pass to the error handler function. Thanks for your help, anyway.